# Deformable Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Spanier's *Algebraic Topology*, he states the following lemma:

"A space $X$ is deformable into a subspace A if and only if the inclusion map $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ has a right homotopy inverse."

Here is the proof he gives going from the second statement to the first:

"If $i$ has a right homotopy inverse $f:X\rightarrow A$, then $i\circ f \simeq 1_{X}$. Let $F:X\times I \rightarrow X$ be a homotopy from $1_{X}$ to  $i\circ f$; then $F(x,0) = x$, so $F$ is a deformation of $X$, and $F(X\times 1) = i\circ f(X) \subset A$, so $X$ is deformable into $A$."

My question is why is $i\circ f(X)$ a subset of A? Is it just by definition of the inclusion map or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ maps $X$ into $A$ and $i$ is just the identity on $A$. It is a trivial consequence of the definitions of $i$ and $f$.

Comment: My mistake. The image of $i$ in $X$ is $A$, so the image of $i \ f$ is contained in $A$.

Comment: $i(X)$ is $A$ by definition?

Comment: You are confusing the functions now. $i$ is a function on $A$. Just picture the composition $i \ f$. The space $X$ is mapped into the subspace $A$. Then the inclusion map is the just the identity so that $i \ f$ is just $f$ if we regard $A$ as contained in $X$.

Comment: The last sentence is not really true. When we regard an injection $i : C \to D$ as an inclusion map we really are identifying $C$ with its image $i(C) \subseteq D$. This identification  comes from the induced bijection $\bar{i}: C \to i(C)$